# Generating a list of links with prefix "The " removed points to empty Tiddler instead of the real Tiddler

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I'm trying to create a tiddler that's an alphabetical list of all the tiddlers in my tiddlywiki. I've gotten it to work to a certain point with this code:

```
A
<<list-links "[prefix[A]][removeprefix[The ]]+[prefix[A]]">>
B
<<list-links "[prefix[B]][removeprefix[The ]]+[prefix[B]]">>
C
<<list-links "[prefix[C]][removeprefix[The ]]+[prefix[C]]">>
```

What I've done here is that some of my tiddlers are prefixed with the word "The ", so I'm removing the prefix and just using non-prefixed name of the tiddler to display in the index. This is also working fine, it's finding all the tiddlers, stripping out the leading "The " if there is one and then creating a link to a tiddler.

Here is the problem, instead of linking to the actually tiddler, such as "The Mytiddler", it's creating a link to "Mytiddler" instead, which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to display the non-prefixed tiddler name in the list, but have it link to the actual tiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for the `filter`, `subfilter`, and `sortsub` operators, which let you run another filter on the contents of a filter without affecting the values in the main filter pipeline.

Here's a complete solution:

```
\define myprefix(letter) [removeprefix[The ]prefix[$letter$]]
\define mysort() [search-replace::regexp[^The ],[]]

\define render-letter(letter) <<list-links "[filter<myprefix $letter$>] [prefix[$letter$]] +[sortsub<mysort>]">>

<$list filter="A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z" variable="currentLetter">
  <<currentLetter>>
    
  <$macrocall $name="render-letter" letter=<<currentLetter>>/>
</$list>
```

And an explanation (not in order):

```
\define render-letter(letter) <<list-links "[filter<myprefix $letter$>] [prefix[$letter$]] +[sortsub<mysort>]">>
```

First we create a macro to render each letter. Rather than using the `removeprefix` filter operator, we delegate to the filter we called `myprefix`:

```
\define myprefix(letter) [removeprefix[The ]prefix[$letter$]]
```

The result is that the first filter run matches everything prefixed with `The`  and the specified letter, but its outputs are the actual tiddler names, rather than the tiddler names with the prefix removed.

We actually don't need to use `filter` at all here, because the `removeprefix` operator is not necessary – just as effective would be `[prefix[The $letter$]]`. But I've left this in to demonstrate the use of `filter`, since if you were trying to do something a little more complicated, this solution might not work.

At the end of the pipeline we use `sortsub` to combine all of the runs into a single properly sorted list. The filter used for `sortsub` represents the key the items will be sorted on, and in this case we do a regular expression search and replace, replacing `The`  at the start of any tiddler names in the list with nothing:

```
\define mysort() [search-replace::regexp[^The ],[]]
```

You can easily handle additional cases in the regex here (e.g., by separating them with `|`), if you added other runs for removed prefixes.)

This accomplishes everything in your original question, but to produce a complete version of this tiddler, here's an easy way to render this for every letter:

```
<$list filter="A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z" variable="currentLetter">
  <<currentLetter>>
    
  <$macrocall $name="render-letter" letter=<<currentLetter>>/>
</$list>
```

Our “filter” here is just a list of “tiddler names”, which presumably don't actually exist in your wiki but will be iterated through in sequence in the body of the `$list` widget. For each one we call the `render-letter` macro on that letter, and you have your alphabetical list of tiddlers subdivided by letter.

Comment: This is perfect, I eventually tried something like this on my own, but I just couldn't get the syntax correct. This is amazing, thanks!